# How to improve the performance of a C# Entity Framework Core query with contains multiple table joins?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We are currently working on a product which has a GET endpoint that retrieves data from multiple tables in PostgreSQL database using C# Entity Framework Core. The data retrieval takes around 30 minutes time when run locally, and we would like for it to be reduced to a time duration under 15s. We would be grateful if you could help us know any other approach that we could try to improve the performance.

This is the code in the repository layer:

```cs
public async Task<ResultDataList<Core.Models.Deal>> GetDeals(DealFilterData dealFilterData, int pageNumber, int pageSize,
                                                             string sortField, string sortOrder)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Generating query for retrieving Deals data from the database...");
    _logger.LogInformation("Deals Query Parameters passed: BrandId - {brandId}, DealTypeId - {dealTypeId}, " +
                            "ShipId - {shipId}, LeadNumberOfNights - {leadNumberOfNights}, " +
                            "SearchDestination - {searchDestination}, SearchKeyword - {searchKeyword}, " +
                            "IsActive - {isActive}, PageNumber - {pageNumber}, PageSize - {pageSize}, SortField - {sortField}, " +
                            "SortOrder - {sortOrder}",
                            dealFilterData.BrandId, dealFilterData.DealTypeId, dealFilterData.ShipId, 
                            dealFilterData.LeadNumberOfNights, dealFilterData.SearchDestination, 
                            dealFilterData.SearchKeyword, dealFilterData.IsActive, pageNumber, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder);

    var query = _dbContext.Deals.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

    if (dealFilterData.BrandId != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.BrandId == dealFilterData.BrandId);
    }

    if (dealFilterData.IsActive != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.IsActive == dealFilterData.IsActive);
    }

    if (dealFilterData.DealTypeId != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.DealTypeId == dealFilterData.DealTypeId);
    }

    if (dealFilterData.LeadNumberOfNights != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.LeadNumberOfNights == dealFilterData.LeadNumberOfNights);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dealFilterData.LeadOffers))
    {
        decimal startPrice, endPrice;
        _filterHelper.GetFilterPrices(dealFilterData.LeadOffers, out startPrice, out endPrice);
        query = query.Where(d => d.LeadOffers.OrderBy(l => l.Price).First().Price >= startPrice &&
                                        d.LeadOffers.OrderBy(l => l.Price).First().Price <= endPrice);
    }

    if (dealFilterData.ShipId != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.ShipId == dealFilterData.ShipId);
    }

    if (dealFilterData.SearchDestination != null)
    {
        List<string> searchDestinations = GetSplitCapitalizedWordList(dealFilterData.SearchDestination);

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DealDestination>(false);

        foreach (string searchDestination in searchDestinations)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.DestinationName.StartsWith(searchDestination + ","));
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.DestinationName.Contains("," + searchDestination + ","));
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.DestinationName.EndsWith("," + searchDestination));
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.DestinationName.Contains(searchDestination) && !d.DestinationName.Contains(","));
        }

        query = query.Where(d => d.DealDestinations.AsQueryable().Any(predicate));
    }

    if (dealFilterData.SearchKeyword != null)
    {
        List<string> searchKeywords = GetSplitCapitalizedWordList(dealFilterData.SearchKeyword);

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DealKeyword>(false);

        foreach (string searchKeyword in searchKeywords)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.StartsWith(searchKeyword + ","));
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.Contains("," + searchKeyword + ","));
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.EndsWith("," + searchKeyword));
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.Contains(searchKeyword) && !d.Keyword.Contains(","));
        }

        query = query.Where(d => d.DealKeywords.AsQueryable().Any(predicate));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dealFilterData.CreatedDateRange))
    {
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        _filterHelper.GetFilterDates(dealFilterData.CreatedDateRange, out startDate, out endDate);
        query = query.Where(d => d.CreatedDate >= startDate && d.CreatedDate <= endDate);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dealFilterData.ModifiedDateRange))
    {
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        _filterHelper.GetFilterDates(dealFilterData.ModifiedDateRange, out startDate, out endDate);
        query = query.Where(d => d.ModifiedDate >= startDate && d.ModifiedDate <= endDate);
    }

    var sortFields = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<DealEntity, object>>>
    {
        { "id", d => d.Id },
        { "brandid", d => d.BrandId },
        { "dealtypeid", d => d.DealTypeId },
        { "leadnumberofnights", d => d.LeadNumberOfNights },
        { "isitineraryavailable", d => d.IsItineraryAvailable! },
        { "isactive", d => d.IsActive! },
        { "createddate", d => d.CreatedDate },
        { "modifieddate", d => d.ModifiedDate }
    };

    query = query.Sort(sortFields, sortField, sortOrder);

    int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

    query = query.Paginate(pageNumber, pageSize);

    List<Core.Models.Deal> dealsList = await query.Include(d => d.Ship)
                                                    .ThenInclude(s => s!.ShipInfoItems)
                                                    .Include(d => d.Ship)
                                                    .ThenInclude(s => s!.ShipCabins)
                                                    .GetDealData()
                                                    .ToListAsync();

    _logger.LogInformation("Retrieved {number} Deals.", dealsList.Count);

    return dealsList.GetResultDataList(totalCount, pageNumber, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder);
}
```

Only the relevant data is selected through the following method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Core.Models.Deal> GetDealData(this IQueryable<Data.Entities.Deal> query)
{
    return query.Select(deal => new Core.Models.Deal()
    {
        Id = deal.Id,
        MetaTitle = deal.MetaTitle,
        MetaDescription = deal.MetaDescription,
        LeadNumberOfNights = deal.LeadNumberOfNights,
        IsItineraryAvailable = deal.IsItineraryAvailable,
        DisplayData = new()
        {
            ListTypeDescription = deal.ListTypeDescription,
            ListImageUrl = deal.ListImageUrl,
            ListImageAltText = deal.ListImageAltText,
            ListTitle = deal.ListTitle,
            ListSubtitle = deal.ListSubtitle
        },
        DealTypeId = deal.DealTypeId,
        BrandId = deal.BrandId,
        Ship = deal.Ship != null ? new Core.Models.AllShipData().MapToCoreAllShipData(deal.Ship) : null,
        SearchDestinations = deal.DealDestinations.Select(sd => sd.DestinationName).First().Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None).ToList(),
        SearchKeywords = deal.DealKeywords.Count > 0 
                                ? deal.DealKeywords.Select(dk => dk.Keyword).First().Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
                                : new List<string>(),
        DealOverviews = deal.DealOverviews.Select(dow => new Core.Models.DealOverview()
        {
            Id = dow.Id,
            Title = dow.Title,
            Subtitle = dow.Subtitle,
            ImageUrl = dow.ImageUrl,
            ImageAltText = dow.ImageAltText
        }).ToList(),
        DealGalleries = deal.DealGalleries.Select(dg => new Core.Models.Gallery()
        {
            Id = dg.Id,
            ImageUrl = dg.ImageUrl,
            ImageAltText = dg.ImageAltText
        }).ToList(),
        Video = deal.DealVideos.Select(dv => new Core.Models.Video()
        {
            Id = dv.Id,
            Title = dv.Title,
            Subtitle = dv.Subtitle,
            Description = dv.Description,
            ImageUrl = dv.ThumbnailImageUrl,
            ImageAltText = dv.ThumbnailImageAltText,
            VideoUrl = dv.VideoUrl
        }).FirstOrDefault()!,
        DealAmenities = deal.DealAmenities.Select(da => new Core.Models.BasicAmenityData()
        {
            Id = da.AmenityId,
            Name = da.Amenity.Name,
            IconUrl = da.Amenity.IconUrl,
            IconAltText = da.Amenity.IconAltText
        }).ToList(),
        DealHighlights = deal.DealHighlights.Select(dh => new Core.Models.DescriptionData()
        {
            Id = dh.Id,
            Description = dh.Description
        }).ToList(),
        LeadOffers = deal.LeadOffers.OrderBy(lo => lo.Price).Select(lo => new Core.Models.LeadOffer()
        {
            Id = lo.Id,
            Title = lo.Title,
            Price = lo.Price
        }).ToList(),
        DealSimilarDealDeals = deal.DealSimilarDealDeals.Select(dsd => new Core.Models.BasicDealData()
        {
            Id = dsd.SimilarDealId,
            DisplayData = new()
            {
                ListTypeDescription = dsd.SimilarDeal!.ListTypeDescription!,
                ListImageUrl = dsd.SimilarDeal.ListImageUrl,
                ListImageAltText = dsd.SimilarDeal.ListImageAltText!,
                ListTitle = dsd.SimilarDeal.ListTitle,
                ListSubtitle = dsd.SimilarDeal.ListSubtitle,
                DealTypeId = dsd.SimilarDeal.DealTypeId,
                ShipName = dsd.SimilarDeal.Ship != null ? dsd.SimilarDeal.Ship.Name : null
            },
            LeadNumberOfNights = dsd.SimilarDeal.LeadNumberOfNights,
            LeadOffers = dsd.SimilarDeal.LeadOffers.OrderBy(lo => lo.Price)
                                                    .Select(lo => new Core.Models.LeadOffer()
            {
                Id = lo.Id,
                Title = lo.Title,
                Price = lo.Price
            }).ToList(),
            Amenities = dsd.SimilarDeal.DealAmenities.Select(da => new Core.Models.BasicAmenityData()
            {
                Id = da.Amenity.Id,
                Name = da.Amenity.Name,
                IconUrl = da.Amenity.IconUrl,
                IconAltText = da.Amenity.IconAltText
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList(),
        IsActive = deal.IsActive,
        CreatedDate = deal.CreatedDate,
        ModifiedDate = deal.ModifiedDate
    });
}
```

Following is a sample of the query generated through Entity Framework. The query executes faster in the database in around 46 seconds, but when executed through the application, it takes around 30 minutes.

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.meta_title, t.meta_description, t.lead_number_of_nights, t.is_itinerary_available, t.list_type_description, t.list_image_url, t.list_image_alt_text, t.list_title, t.list_subtitle, 
t.deal_type_id, t.brand_id, s.id IS NOT NULL, s.id, s.created_date, s.is_active, s.modified_date, s.name, s0.id, s0.created_date, s0.description, s0.modified_date, s0.ship_id, s1.id, s1.created_date, 
s1.description, s1.image_alt_text, s1.image_key_id, s1.image_url, s1.modified_date, s1.ship_id, s1.title, d1.destination_name, d1.id, (
 SELECT count(*)::int
 FROM deal_keyword AS d2
 WHERE t.id = d2.deal_id) > 0, d3.keyword, d3.id, d4.id, d4.title, d4.subtitle, d4.image_url, d4.image_alt_text, d5.id, d5.image_url, d5.image_alt_text, t0."Id", t2."Id", t2."Name", 
 t2."IconUrl", t2."IconAltText", t2.deal_id, t2.id0, d8.id, d8.description, l.id, l.title, l.price, t3.similar_deal_id, t3.list_type_description, t3.list_image_url, t3.list_image_alt_text, 
 t3.list_title, t3.list_subtitle, t3.deal_type_id, t3.name, t3.lead_number_of_nights, t3.deal_id, t3.id, t3.id0, t3.id1, t3.title, t3.price, t3."Id2", t3."Name0", t3."IconUrl", 
 t3."IconAltText", t3.deal_id0, t3.amenity_id, t.is_active, t.created_date, t.modified_date, t0."Title", t0."Subtitle", t0."Description", t0."ImageUrl", t0."ImageAltText", 
 t0."VideoUrl", t0.c
 FROM (
 SELECT d.id, d.brand_id, d.created_date, d.deal_type_id, d.is_active, d.is_itinerary_available, d.lead_number_of_nights, d.list_image_alt_text, d.list_image_url, 
 d.list_subtitle, d.list_title, d.list_type_description, d.meta_description, d.meta_title, d.modified_date, d.ship_id
 FROM deal AS d
 WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT 1       
 FROM deal_destination AS d0
 WHERE d.id = d0.deal_id AND ('KANDY,' = '' OR ((d0.destination_name LIKE 'KANDY,' || '%' ESCAPE '') AND 
 left(d0.destination_name, length('KANDY,'))::character varying = 'KANDY,'::character varying) OR ',KANDY,' = '' OR strpos(d0.destination_name, ',KANDY,') > 0 OR ',KANDY' = '' OR 
 right(d0.destination_name, length(',KANDY'))::character varying = ',KANDY'::character varying OR (('KANDY' = '' OR strpos(d0.destination_name, 'KANDY') > 0) AND NOT 
 (strpos(d0.destination_name, ',') > 0)) OR 'GALLE,' = '' OR ((d0.destination_name LIKE 'GALLE,' || '%' ESCAPE '') AND 
 left(d0.destination_name, length('GALLE,'))::character varying = 'GALLE,'::character varying) OR ',GALLE,' = '' OR strpos(d0.destination_name, ',GALLE,') > 0 OR ',GALLE' = '' OR 
 right(d0.destination_name, length(',GALLE'))::character varying = ',GALLE'::character varying OR (('GALLE' = '' OR strpos(d0.destination_name, 'GALLE') > 0) AND NOT 
 (strpos(d0.destination_name, ',') > 0))))
 ORDER BY d.id
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 40) AS t
 LEFT JOIN ship AS s ON t.ship_id = s.id
 LEFT JOIN ship_info_items AS s0 ON s.id = s0.ship_id
 LEFT JOIN ship_cabin AS s1 ON s.id = s1.ship_id
 LEFT JOIN deal_destination AS d1 ON t.id = d1.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN deal_keyword AS d3 
 ON t.id = d3.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN deal_overview AS d4 ON t.id = d4.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN deal_gallery AS d5 ON t.id = d5.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN (    
 SELECT t1."Id", t1."Title", t1."Subtitle", t1."Description", t1."ImageUrl", t1."ImageAltText", t1."VideoUrl", t1.c, t1.deal_id
 FROM (        
 SELECT d6.id AS "Id", d6.title AS "Title", d6.subtitle AS "Subtitle", d6.description AS "Description", d6.thumbnail_image_url AS "ImageUrl", d6.thumbnail_image_alt_text AS "ImageAltText", 
 d6.video_url AS "VideoUrl", 1 AS c, d6.deal_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d6.deal_id ORDER BY d6.id) AS row      
 FROM deal_video AS d6 ) AS t1
 WHERE t1.row <= 1) AS t0 ON t.id = t0.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT d7.amenity_id AS "Id", a.name AS "Name", a.icon_url AS "IconUrl", 
 a.icon_alt_text AS "IconAltText", d7.deal_id, a.id AS id0
 FROM deal_amenity AS d7
 INNER JOIN amenity AS a ON d7.amenity_id = a.id) AS t2 ON t.id = t2.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN deal_highlight AS d8 ON t.id = d8.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN lead_offers AS l ON t.id = l.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT d9.similar_deal_id, d10.list_type_description, d10.list_image_url, 
 d10.list_image_alt_text, d10.list_title, d10.list_subtitle, d10.deal_type_id, s2.name, d10.lead_number_of_nights, d9.deal_id, d10.id, s2.id AS id0, l0.id AS id1, l0.title, l0.price, 
 t4."Id" AS "Id2", t4."Name" AS "Name0", t4."IconUrl", t4."IconAltText", t4.deal_id AS deal_id0, t4.amenity_id
 FROM deal_similar_deal AS d9
 INNER JOIN deal AS d10 ON d9.similar_deal_id = d10.id
 LEFT JOIN ship AS s2 ON d10.ship_id = s2.id
 LEFT JOIN lead_offers AS l0 ON d10.id = l0.deal_id
 LEFT JOIN (    
 SELECT a0.id AS "Id", a0.name AS "Name", a0.icon_url AS "IconUrl", a0.icon_alt_text AS "IconAltText", d11.deal_id, d11.amenity_id
 FROM deal_amenity AS d11    
 INNER JOIN amenity AS a0 ON d11.amenity_id = a0.id  ) AS t4 ON d10.id = t4.deal_id) AS t3 ON t.id = t3.deal_id
 ORDER BY t.id, s.id, s0.id, s1.id, d1.id, d3.id, d4.id, d5.id, t0."Id", 
 t2.deal_id, t2."Id", t2.id0, d8.id, l.price, l.id, t3.deal_id, t3.similar_deal_id, t3.id, t3.id0, t3.price, t3.id1, t3.deal_id0, t3.amenity_id;
```

Following are the database table structures and their non-clustered indexes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS brand 
(
    mos_brand_id INT NOT NULL,
    media_api_key VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    brand_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    deal_template_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT brand_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mos_brand_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amenity_type 
(
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT amenity_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amenity 
(
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    amenity_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    brand_id INT NOT NULL,
    icon_image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    icon_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    icon_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT amenity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT amenity_amenityTypeId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (amenity_type_id) REFERENCES amenity_type(id),
    CONSTRAINT amenity_brandId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand(mos_brand_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_type 
(
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ship 
(
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ship_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ship_cabin 
(
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    ship_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ship_cabin_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT ship_cabin_shipId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (ship_id) REFERENCES ship(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ship_info_items 
(
    id SERIAL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    ship_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ship_info_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT ship_info_items_shipId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (ship_id) REFERENCES ship(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal 
(
    id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('deal_sequence'),
    meta_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    meta_description VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    lead_number_of_nights INT NOT NULL,
    lead_price NUMERIC(8, 2) NOT NULL,
    is_itinerary_available BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    list_type_description VARCHAR(70), -- Most Requested --
    list_image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    list_image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    list_image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    list_title VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    list_subtitle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    deal_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    ship_id INT,
    brand_id INT NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_dealTypeId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_type_id) REFERENCES deal_type(id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_shipId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (ship_id) REFERENCES ship(id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_brandId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_similar_deal 
(
    deal_id INT,
    similar_deal_id INT,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_similar_deal_pkey PRIMARY KEY (deal_id, similar_deal_id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_similar_deal_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_similar_deal_similarDealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (similar_deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_amenity 
(
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    amenity_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_amenity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (deal_id, amenity_id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_amenity_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_amenity_amenityId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (amenity_id) REFERENCES amenity(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_overview 
(
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    subtitle VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_overview_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_overview_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_gallery 
(
    id SERIAL,
    image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_gallery_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_gallery_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_video 
(
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    subtitle VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    thumbnail_image_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    thumbnail_image_alt_text VARCHAR(50),
    thumbnail_image_key_id UUID NOT NULL,
    video_url VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_video_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_video_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_highlight 
(
    id SERIAL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_highlight_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_highlight_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_destination 
(
    id SERIAL,
    destination_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_destination_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_destination_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deal_keyword 
(
    id SERIAL,
    keyword VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT deal_keyword_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT deal_keyword_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lead_offers 
(
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(8, 2) NOT NULL,
    deal_id INT,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    modified_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT lead_offers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT lead_offers_dealId_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (deal_id) REFERENCES deal(id)
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_general_search 
ON deal (brand_id, is_active, deal_type_id, lead_number_of_nights);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_overview_deal_id 
ON deal_overview (deal_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_gallery_deal_id 
ON deal_gallery (deal_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_video_deal_id 
ON deal_video (deal_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_highlight_deal_id 
ON deal_highlight (deal_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_lead_offers_deal_id 
ON lead_offers (deal_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_destination_deal_id ON deal_destination (deal_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_destination_destination_name ON deal_destination (destination_name);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_keyword_deal_id ON deal_keyword (deal_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_keyword_keyword ON deal_keyword (keyword);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_ship_general_search ON ship (is_active);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_ship_cabin_ship_id ON ship_cabin (ship_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_ship_info_items_ship_id ON ship_info_items (ship_id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_amenity_amenity_type_id ON amenity (amenity_type_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_amenity_general_search ON amenity (brand_id, is_active);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_type_general_search ON deal_type (is_active);
```

- We tried adding indexes to deal destination and deal keyword table columns involved in the where condition.
- Since the query execution plan points to higher costs in table joins, we tried removing deal destination and deal keyword tables, bringing two columns that could be added to the main Deal table.
- We tried adding non-clustered indexes to the new columns mentioned above to have been added to main Deal table.
- Verified that we have already added non-clustered indexes to the foreign key columns involved in the table joins.

None of the above made any significant difference in the time that it takes to execute.

Comment: Whats the generated query that is run, and how does the schema look like, including all indices and foreign keys?

Comment: @Polygnome I included the database table structures and the non-clustered indexes above.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this SQL statement? In plain text, as an update of your question.

Comment: Don't use EF, use database resources.

Comment: Why have 4 conditions on the destination when they all fall into the `Contains(searchDestination)` one?

Comment: In CQRS style, you could set up a table where you save projections of your data ready to be queried and presented. Of course you would need to make sure that this "viewmodel" store is eventually consistent.

Comment: @MateusZampol this has nothing to do with CQRS. CQRS isn't a database design methodology. In fact it borrowed concepts from database designs that existed for several decades already - separate OLTP and reporting databases.  Besides, this query would be slow with a single table as well, because it uses unindexable operations, like searching in the middle of a string

Comment: @GHDevOps EF generates SQL queries. If the filters are bad or there are no indexes, the queries will always be slow. And in this case, the filters are bad.

Comment: @Dinusha the JOINs would only cause delays if there were no indexes. Far worse is the use of `Contains` and `EndsWith`, because such searches *can't* use any indexes and result in a full table scan. If you use `Name LIKE '%potato'` in a 1M row table, you have to scan all 1M rows to find even a single match, even if the `Name` field was indexed

Comment: @GHDevOps if you think so, try comparing the execution plans of `LIKE 'potato%'` and `LIKE '%potato'`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Name LIKE '%potato'` can use an index, if you create a special one for this case.

Comment: @FrankHeikens if you reverse the string, you can use a normal index too. The way the query is now though, the string searches will force full table scans. Combine that with paging, it will perform a full scan for every page. I see other problems too, like a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression that returns rows where `t1.row <= 1`. This shouldn't be done in EF Core or against the OLTP tables

Comment: @Dinusha When there is such a big difference between your .NET app and another client, I would recommend running a profiler to better understand what is taking so much more time with EF Core. Maybe the extra 29m is actually your system running low on memory or something

Answer (score 2):

Constructs like this:

```
    foreach (string searchKeyword in searchKeywords)
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.StartsWith(searchKeyword + ","));
        predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.Contains("," + searchKeyword + ","));
        predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.EndsWith("," + searchKeyword));
        predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Keyword.Contains(searchKeyword) && !d.Keyword.Contains(","));
    }
```

Are going to kill any query performance. This is non-index-able, and is ensuring every query is querying against each text column 4 times with two %term% queries, one term% and one %term query. Even though the first 3 queries are intending (or unintentionally) to do exact keyword matches, while the last one will do a contains for a partial match but only if there is a single keyword.

If you want to improve performance then consider changing these to either:

Split Keywords etc. into many-to-many or one-to-many relationships. For instance in a one-to-many having a DealKeywords table containing a DealId and Keyword. Then when searching by keyword you can simply have:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Keywords.Any(k => k.Keyword == keyword));
query = query.Where(x => x.Keywords.Any(k => k.Keyword.Contains(keyword)));
```

Even better is let the user specify whether they want an Equals vs. StartsWith vs. Contains before defaulting to the worst possible option for all queries. This could be a drop-down selection for text fields with those options or allowing users to append wildcard characters like "*" or "%". This can then pass something like "term" vs. "term*" vs "*term*" which you can inspect on the service and perform the appropriate filter.

The other option without a schema change would be to use bracketing delimiters for delimited text columns. For instance, instead of comma-delimited, use bracketed pipes. Each keyword is formatted as "|term|" When appending terms in your entity model you can use an unmapped `List<string>` for Keywords, then a raw keywords backing field.

```
public string Keywords {get; protected set; } = string.Empty;
private List<string>? _keywordList;
[NotMapped]
public List<string> KeywordList
{
    get => _keywordList ??= string.Split(Keywords, "|", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

public void AddKeyword(keyword)
{
    if (KeywordList.Any(x => x == keyword)) return;
    KeywordLists.Add(keyword);
    Keywords = $"|{string.Join(KeywordList, "|")}|";
}

public void RemoveKeyword(keyword)
{
    KeywordList.Remove(keyword); 
    Keywords = $"|{string.Join(KeywordList, "|")}|";
}

public void ClearKeywords()
{
    _keywordList.Clear();
    Keywords = string.Empty;
}
```

Then your query filtering can always consider a keyword to be wrapped by Pipes, whether the first, last, or single keyword value.  The downside of this approach is that like any `[NotMapped]` column, the convenience of the `List<string>` KeywordLists cannot be used in the query. Query expressions need to still use the raw `string` Keywords value.

Normalizing the keywords in a separate table would be what I recommend as it can provide better querying performance and more flexibility to the searching.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion above to use the '|' character as a separator. After implementing that approach along with Deal Search Destinations and Keywords in the main table, the query started performing better.